# Input Array Push Extra values

Tags: javascript

So I have an input text with the name filesChosen[]. This input is empty. I would like through javascript to be able to add values to that input.

```
<input type="text" name="filesChosen[]" id="filesChosen[]" multiple="true" style="display: none" onchange="addFiles()" required>
```

I have tried the following but it seems to only work with the first value:

```
document.getElementsByName("filesChosen")[x].value = "1" ;
```

Is there a way to Push a new element to the input?

I am getting the following error when X >0

***26:400 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')***

**Edit:
Change to document.getElementsByName("filesChosen[]"), getting same error**

Comment: There's no element with the name `filesChosen`. The name is `filesChosen[]`.

Comment: And no you cannot "push another element". You can *create* an element and add it to your page or form or whatever.

Comment: how can I add the Created Element to a text input? AppendChild?

Comment: How is the element created, what type of element do we talk about? Is it a string? What is the goal. Seems like you have one input. But you’re setting values on index/input that does not exist.

Comment: I have an array with a dynamic size I want to add to the Text Input

Comment: So you want to add an array to an input of type text? So what does this array contain, strings?

Comment: Correct. A String Array. I want to add it to an input with name[]

Answer (score 0):

You left the `[]` out of the name when calling `document.getElementsByName()`.

If there's only one element with this name, you shouldn't use a variable to index it, use `[0]`.

Use `+=` to append to the value.

```
document.getElementsByName("filesChosen[]")[0].value += "1" ;
```

Comment: getting same error with document.getElementsByName("filesChosen[]")[x].value = "1" ;

Comment: Is the value of `x` more than the number of inputs you have with this name?

Comment: How do you set `x`?

Comment: The input is empty, I am trying to dynamically add more values to the Text input

Comment: The array index is indexing the list of elements returned by `document.getElementsByName()`. If you only have one input, just use `[0]` to select it.

Comment: To add to the input value, use `.value += "1";`

Comment: Why are you using a name ending with `[]` if there's only one input? That's usually used when you have multiple inputs and they should be put into an array on the back end.

Comment: I want to add multiple values to the input. Start the input text with just one and keep adding them depending on the amout of data in my array

Comment: What array? Maybe you should just use `.value = array.join(',')`.

Comment: I want to add a String Array with a dynamic size to a text input with name[] is that possible or would I have to create multiple inputs through javascript?

Comment: You can append them to a sting variable. And put that string as input value

Comment: @CarlosCastillo `+=` will add to the input, I already updated the answer to show how to do that.

Comment: But it won't be an array in the input, it will just be a text string. You could add delimiters, so that the server can split it up.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `style="display: none"` CSS property you have on there might be interfering with your code. But if that's not it then you could try this syntax:

```js
const input = document.querySelectorAll('[name="filesChosen[]"]')[0]
input.value = 'Some value'
```

```html
<input type="text" name="filesChosen[]" id="filesChosen[]" multiple="true" onchange="addFiles()" required >
```